# Custom domain name to serve Python packages from Google Artifact Registry?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dns, custom-domain

We're serving Python packages through Google's Artifact Registry. Actually the URL is the "default" one, so

```
https://[REGION].pkg.dev/[PROJECT_ID]/.....
```

but what if we wanted to use a custom domain name? For example we'd like to serve packages from a custom domain link like

```
https://[MY-CUSTOM-DOMAIN]/...
```

Is there an official way to do that? What are my options?

Comment: Does this [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/hack-your-own-custom-domains-container-registry) answer your question? 
"...you can simply use your existing Google Container Registry or Artifact Registry to store your images, and build a "reverse proxy" on top of it to forward the incoming requests while still serving the traffic on the custom domain name you own."

Comment: @FaridShumbar yes, that's actually what a Google Community Team member told me, see [this post](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/Custom-domain-name-to-serve-Python-packages-from-Google-Artifact/m-p/184239#M437). Thank you, seems that the reverse proxy is the only way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment for visibility.

Consider using the [reverse proxy](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/hack-your-own-custom-domains-container-registry) as described in the article:

> ...you can simply use your existing Google Container Registry or
> Artifact Registry to store your images, and build a "reverse proxy" on
> top of it to forward the incoming requests while still serving the
> traffic on the custom domain name you own.

Comment: Does this work only for public access, or does it work for authenticated access too?